Video streaming error: Uncaught (in promise) NotSupportedError: Failed to load because no supported source was found
Here is my problem: I have one video src 1080p (on the frontend). On the frontend, I send this video-route to the backend:
const req = async()=>{try{const res = await axios.get('/catalog/item',{params:{SeriesName:seriesName}});return {data:res.data};}catch(err){console.log(err);return false;}}const fetchedData = await req();-On the backend i return seriesName.Now i can make a full path,what the video is,and where it is,code:

const videoUrl = 'C:/Users/arMori/Desktop/RedditClone/reddit/public/videos';console.log('IT VideoURL',videoUrl);

const selectedFile = `${videoUrl}/${fetchedData.data.VideoSource}/${seriesName}-1080p.mp4`
console.log(`ITS'S SELECTED FILE: ${selectedFile}`);

Ok, I have my src 1080p, now is the time to send it to the backend:
const response = await axios.post('/videoFormat', {videoUrl:selectedFile})console.log('Это консоль лог путей: ',response.data);const videoPaths = response.data;

Backend takes it and FFMpqg makes two types of resolution,720p and 480p,save it to the temp storage on backend, and then returns two routes where these videos stores
async videoUpload(videoUrl:string){try{const tempDir = C:/Users/arMori/Desktop/RedditClone/reddit_back/src/video/temp;const inputFile = videoUrl;console.log('VIDEOURL: ',videoUrl);

        const outputFiles = [];
        
        await this.createDirectories(tempDir);        
        outputFiles.push(await this.convertVideo(inputFile, '1280x720', '720p.mp4'));
        outputFiles.push(await this.convertVideo(inputFile, '854x480', '480p.mp4'));
        console.log('OUTUPT FILES SERVICE: ',outputFiles);
        
        return outputFiles;

    }catch(err){
        console.error('VideoFormatterService Error: ',err);
        
    }
}

private convertVideo(inputPath:string,resolution:string,outputFileName:string):Promise<string>{
    const temp = `C:/Users/arMori/Desktop/RedditClone/reddit_back/src/video/temp`;
    return new Promise(async(resolve,reject)=>{
        const height = resolution.split('x')[1];
        console.log('HIEGHT: ',height);
        
        const outputDir = `C:/Users/arMori/Desktop/RedditClone/reddit_back/src/video/temp/${height}p`;
        const outputPath = join(outputDir, outputFileName);
        const isExists = await fs.access(outputPath).then(() => true).catch(() => false);
        if(isExists){ 
            console.log(`File already exists: ${outputPath}`);
            return resolve(outputPath)
        };
        ffmpeg(inputPath)
        .size(`${resolution}`)
        .videoCodec('libx264') // Кодек H.264
        .audioCodec('aac') 
        .output(outputPath)
        .on('end',()=>resolve(outputPath))
        .on('error',(err)=>reject(err))
        .run()
            
    })
}

private async createDirectories(temp:string){
    try{
        const dir720p = `${temp}/720p`;
        const dir480p = `${temp}/480p`;
        const dir720pExists = await fs.access(dir720p).then(() => true).catch(() => false);
        const dir480pExists = await fs.access(dir480p).then(() => true).catch(() => false);
        if(dir720pExists && dir480pExists){
            console.log('FILES ALIVE');
            return;
        }
        if (!dir720pExists) {
            await fs.mkdir(dir720p, { recursive: true });
            console.log('Папка 720p создана');
        }
        
        if (!dir480pExists) {
            await fs.mkdir(dir480p, { recursive: true });
            console.log('Папка 480p создана');
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Ошибка при создании директорий:', err);
    }
}

Continue frontentd code:
let videoPath;

if (quality === '720p') {
        videoPath = videoPaths[0];
} else if (quality === '480p') {
        videoPath = videoPaths[1];
}

if (!videoPath) {
        console.error('Video path not found!');
        return;
}

// Получаем видео по его пути
console.log('VIDEOPATH LOG: ',videoPath);
    
const videoRes = await axios.get('/videoFormat/getVideo', { 
        params: { path: videoPath } ,
        headers: { Range: 'bytes=0-' },
        responseType: 'blob'
    });
    console.log('Video fetched: ', videoRes);
    const videoBlob = new Blob([videoRes.data], { type: 'video/mp4' });
    const videoURL = URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob);
    return videoURL;
    /* console.log('Видео успешно загружено:', response.data); */
    } catch (error) {
    console.error('Ошибка при загрузке видео:', error);
    }
}

Here I just choose one of the route and make a new GET request (VideoRes), now in the controller in the backend, I'm trying to do a video streaming:
@Public()
    @Get('/getVideo')
    async getVideo(@Query('path') videoPath:string,@Req() req:Request,@Res() res:Response){
        try {
            console.log('PATH ARGUMENT: ',videoPath);
            console.log('VIDEOPATH IN SERVICE: ',videoPath);
        const videoSize = (await fs.stat(videoPath)).size;
        const CHUNK_SIZE = 10 ** 6;
        const range = req.headers['range'] as string | undefined;
        if (!range) {
            return new ForbiddenException('Range не найденно');
        }
        const start = Number(range.replace(/\D/g,""));
        const end = Math.min(start + CHUNK_SIZE,videoSize - 1);

        const contentLength = end - start + 1;
        const videoStream = fsSync.createReadStream(videoPath, { start, end });
        const headers = {
            'Content-Range':`bytes ${start}-${end}/${videoSize}`,
            'Accept-Ranges':'bytes',
            'Content-Length':contentLength,
            'Content-Type':'video/mp4'
        }
        
        res.writeHead(206,headers);

        // Передаем поток в ответ
        videoStream.pipe(res);
        

        // Если возникнет ошибка при стриминге, логируем ошибку
        videoStream.on('error', (error) => {
            console.error('Ошибка при чтении видео:', error);
            res.status(500).send('Ошибка при чтении видео');
        });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Ошибка при обработке запросов:', error);
            return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Ошибка при обработке getVideo запросов' });
        }
    }

Send to the frontend
res.writeHead(206,headers);

In the frontend, I make blob url for video src and return it
const videoBlob = new Blob([videoRes.data], { type: 'video/mp4' });const videoURL = URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob);return videoURL;

And assign src to the video:
useVideo(seriesName,quality).then(src => {
                if (src) {
                    console.log('ITS VIDEOLOGISC GOIDA!');
                    if(!playRef.current) return;
                    
                    const oldURL = playRef.current.src;
                    if (oldURL && oldURL.startsWith('blob:')) {
                        URL.revokeObjectURL(oldURL);
                    }
                    playRef.current.pause();
                    playRef.current.src = '';
                    setQuality(quality);
                    console.log('SRC: ',src);
                    
                    playRef.current.src = src;
                    playRef.current.load();
                    console.log('ITS VIDEOURL GOIDA!');
                    togglePlayPause();
                }
            })
            .catch(err => console.error('Failed to fetch video', err));

But the problem is:

Vinland-Saga:1 Uncaught (in promise) NotSupportedError: Failed to load because no supported source was found

And I don't know why...
I tried everything, but I don't understand why src is incorrect..

(1) Why is your request's start not just a simple const start = 0; instead of this const start = Number(range.replace(/\D/g,"")); that you are using? Note that you cannot slice an MP4, but it can be done with a fragmented MP4. (2) Is FFmpeg getting enough time to fully finish converting before you try to play? (3) Try to save your blob as a File then open that file in a hex editor and show us an image to check if the bytes are correct for MP4... Or else just share the saved file. Use this MP4 file for testing and file sharing.

(1)start = Number(range.replace(/\D/g,"")); it uses to remove unnecessary symbols.I understood my problem.Ffmpeg doesn't have enough time to fully finish converting.I should pick one of teh strategy:
1)It will ones store on the server
2)When user trying to choose one of the quality,server just start converting and converted file return to user.
The second harder to realize and there is a problem,that can happen some mistake while its converting.Perhaps I'll pick the first one.And I'd want to thank you,although I understood it a bit before,but your comment have rights to be the answer!Thanks

I understood my problem now. FFmpeg doesn't have enough time to fully finish converting.
Solution: I should pick one of the strategy:

It will store at once on the server and then I can use it

When user trying to choose one of the quality, the server just starts converting and the converted part of file is returned to user.


The second step is harder to realize and there is a problem, that can happen some mistake while its converting. Perhaps I'll pick the first one.
